# on click remove field,amount get reduced but it shows -ve sign

Tags: javascript

Function to remove fields and substract amount from total:

```
function removeHtmlRow(nxt){
 $("#FD"+nxt).remove();
  var totAmtR = 0;
   $('input.price').each(function (index, cvalue) { 
      if(cvalue.value != '' && cvalue.value > 0){
        totAmtR -= parseFloat(cvalue.value);

      }
  });
  alert(totAmtR);
  $("#totalAmount").val(parseFloat(totAmtR));
```

}

Function to calculate total:

```
function calTotalAmount(){

  var totAmt = 0;

  $('input.price').each(function (index, cvalue) { 
      if(cvalue.value != '' && cvalue.value > 0){
        totAmt += parseFloat(cvalue.value);
      }
  });
  $("#totalAmount").val(parseFloat(totAmt));
}
</script>
```

[screenshot shows: after remove field total show remaining amount with -ve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9dZv.png)

Comment: Please share a working snippet that demonstrate your issue.

Comment: You remove `#FD + nxt` element. Then you iterate through the remaining `input.price` elements and substract it from `totAmtR` what is 0 by default. The result will be negative unless you use `+=` instead of `-=` or `calTotalAmount()` function.

Comment: If you got want to print -ve values, make it as 0 after calculating `totAmtR`  
`totAmtR  < 0 ? 0 : totAmtR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `removeHtmlRow` function you are subtracting everything from 0, so it will be negative. Just recalculate the amount using your existing `calTotalAmount` function:

```
function removeHtmlRow(nxt){
  $("#FD"+nxt).remove();
  calTotalAmount()
```

Comment: @S.A.I mean press the tick next to the answer :)